# Why are memory optimised EC2 instances recommended for high performance database use cases?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am new to AWS and was going through the fundamental course where EC2 types were explained.

It was mentioned that for the high performance database use cases, memory optimised AWS EC2 instance should be used.

Why storage optimised EC2 is not recommended to be used for this use-case as storage optimised focuses on IOPS?

Comment: Is the question why you can't use storage optimised EC2 instance types for high perf DB use cases or why memory optimised EC2 instances should be used? Or was your question just general as it was before my edit, making it quite opinionated?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/359414/to-improve-sql-performance-why-not-just-put-lots-of-ram-rather-than-having-fast

Comment: Amazon RDS uses Amazon EBS for storage, not "instance-attached storage". Therefore, the Storage Optimized instance types are not relevant.

Comment: If you want to understand someone else's recommendation, you should ask **that person**.

Answer (score 1):

Database queries are processed in memory so the more data you can fit in the memory the fast the query can be processed because there will be fewer reads from disk. Further, many databases can hold frequently used data in memory caches allowing some queries to be completely answered without disk reads.

Instances with faster disks will also help when operations can not be performed in memory alone.

The general rule of thumb is that a database will perform better with faster throughput and memory throughput is faster than disk throughput but both can help.